# ti 89 copy on custom menu

Tags: calculator, ti-basic

I have a TI-89 program that creates a custom menu. I want my custom menu to include Copy, Cut, Paste, and Clear Home options, just like you can use in the Home menu under the F1 tools tab. How can these functions be implemented?

```
menu()
Prgm

setFold(myMenu)

Custom

Title "Tools"

Item "Copy"

Item "Cut"

Item "Paste"

Item "Clear Home"

EndCustm

EndPrgm
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no supported way to do this. According to [the TI-89/92 manual](http://education.ti.com/downloads/guidebooks/graphing/8992p/8992bookeng.pdf), on page 303:

> **Note:** When the user selects a menu item, the text defined by that Item command is pasted to the current cursor location.

There's no way to create a custom menu which invokes other actions, short of modifying the TI CAS or installing a patch.